# Android SDK tools 23.0.5 automatically adds appCompact and extends with ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-sdk-tools, android-toolbar

I have updated the Android SDK and when I create new project It automatically adds the `appCompact Support Library version 7` and extends my Activity with `ActionBarActivity`.

What happened to ActionBar? Is it gone? How to get back my ActionBar?

Answer (score 1):

There is a new widget called `Toolbar Widget` it is a successor of `ActionBar`

Toolbar is fully supported in `AppCompat` and has feature and API parity with the framework widget. In `AppCompat`, Toolbar is implemented in the `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` class. There are two ways to use Toolbar:

**Use a Toolbar as an Action Bar** when you want to use the existing Action Bar facilities (such as menu inflation and selection, ActionBarDrawerToggle, and so on) but want to have more control over its appearance.
Use a standalone Toolbar when you want to use the pattern in your app for situations that an Action Bar would not support; for example, showing multiple toolbars on the screen, spanning only part of the width, and so on.

**ActionBar**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id=”@+id/my_awesome_toolbar”
    android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
    android:layout_width=”match_parent”
    android:minHeight=”?attr/actionBarSize”
    android:background=”?attr/colorPrimary” />

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.blah);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

**Standalone**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.blah);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);

    // Set an OnMenuItemClickListener to handle menu item clicks
    toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle the menu item
            return true;
        }
    });

    // Inflate a menu to be displayed in the toolbar
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.your_toolbar_menu);
}
```

For detailed information visit http://android-developers.blogspot.com.au/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

Answer (score 1):

To provide compatibility for previous versions, ADT tools 23 will automatically add it. You can remove them and set lower build tools version.

Answer (score 0):

Either:

- Follow [the instructions](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) to use `appcompat-v7`, or
- Remove `appcompat-v7` from your project, switch to a theme that is based on standard Android (e.g., `Theme.Holo`), and change your activity to inherit from `Activity` instead of `ActionBarActivity`